# How to Download file in Internet Explorer with selenium driver using AutoIT library in C#?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, autoit-c#-wrapper

I want to download a file during Selenium automation in IE,and so far i tried below code by after button click by adding AutoIt library in C# class file ,but this one is not working..
Can any one help what I am missing?

Thanks in advance.

```
IntPtr temp = AutoItX.WinGetHandle("[Class:IEFrame]");
AutoItX.ControlGetHandle(temp, "[Class:DirectUIHWND]");
Thread.Sleep(1000);

AutoItX.WinActivate(temp);
AutoItX.ControlClick("[Class:DirectUIHWND]", "", "");
AutoItX.ControlSend("", "", "[ClassNN:DirectUIHWND]", "{F6}");
Thread.Sleep(500);
AutoItX.ControlSend("", "", "[Class:DirectUIHWND]", "{TAB}");
Thead.Sleep(500);
AutoItX.ControlSend("", "", "[Class:DirectUIHWND]", "{ENTER}");
Thread.Sleep(500);
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually direct selenium to click the button/link to download the file, so that a Windows explorer window appears, and take it from there with AutoIT.

Something like this:

```
driver.[locate the button/link that downloads the file]
driver.[click that button/link]
(perhaps a wait here)
system.[fire up the autoIT executable that handles the windows explorer window]
carry on from there
```

Comment: I dont want to execute any external script as code will run remotely in server and want to use Autoit library to handle IE download popup...Do u have any idea about it?